# 1974 VW Bug Headliner

Tags: vw, beetle

I drive a '74 Volkswagen Super Beetle and I just replaced the headliner. I used the suggested glue and the roof clips but it will not stay up in the back and is beginning to come down in the front. Any suggestions on how to keep it up?

Comment: Can you be more specific about the procedure and equipment you used? Just asking for more suggestions doesn't seem likely to produce any new information for you, without knowing where you're starting from.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using 'Gorilla Glue'.  It makes anything stick to anything.